# How to extract resin "fix" from a brass water pipe?

Tags: water, repair, threading

Some time ago I fell, and broken off my faucet. Manufacturer has already disappeared from the market so the spare part wasn't available.  I printed it in resin, screwed it in using silicone and it worked. For a month. Turns out, resin I was using really dislikes chlorine in the water.

I'll reprint the part in ASA, it should be safe this time, but before I can install it, I need to remove what's left from previous attempt. I tried the tool for removing screws with stripped heads, but it only crushed it a bit and didn't unscrew it.

[image: photo of a stuck piece]

Comment: Do you own some picks?

Comment: @Huesmann like ice picks or lock picks?

Comment: Like these guys: https://www.harborfreight.com/mini-pick-and-hook-set-63697.html

Comment: @Huesmann I do. Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: I see you already got it out, but if this happens to someone else, heating the plastic will make it easier to remove.

Comment: @Ariel plastic, yes. Resin, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some picks to laboriously remove the remaining bits of resin; example:

[image]

Comment: Aaaand it worked. I needed to crush the resin a bit, but I got it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if something like a bolt with a left-hand thread won't work then drilling it out and digging the remains out of the threads would be the tedious option.

And instead of fixing it with silicone I would use ptfe or some plumber's mate or equivalent.